# format a double to 8 decimal places

Tags: c#, format, double

I have a method that i want to return as a double with 8 dp.

so i have a value coming back from a sp and in the code i am simply doing

```
CheckSum = double.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

however, if the sp returns this :1541338.2349537
the returned double only has those 7dp, when i would like it to put a trailing zero on.
like this.. 1541338.23495370

i cant find a method on the double to format it - ie force it to 8dp, other than to return a formatted string.
which i dont want to do.
can someone explain please :)

thanks

nat

Comment: Formatting only makes sense when you convert it into a string. A double will always have the same precision. (15 digits if memory serves)

Comment: Or do you want to round it to 8 dp?

Comment: I don't know why people use abbreviations in their questions. Are we actually expected to know exactly what you mean by `sp`? Because I certainly don't. How hard is it just to type full words?

Comment: I would guess 'stored procedure' given the call to ExecuteScalar.

Comment: I guess i would like it rounded rather than cropped if it gets cropped  doing with ToString("0.00000000")
rounded and formatted to 8dp is what i need. comparing a checksum (of sorts) without the same precision is not going to be very useful

Comment: apologies for abbreviating, shall not do it again - for fear of abuse mostly :-p -I had thought that it was obvious-clearly only to me

Comment: Math.Round(double, int) allows you to specify the number of decimal places. You might want to consider using a Decimal rather than a double if you're worried about precision. It doesn't suffer from the occasional issues you can get with precisions and doubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double d = 0.123456789;
string sDisplayValue = d.ToString("0.00000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double inputValue = 14.42564678942;
inputValue = Math.Round(inputValue, 8);
```

Output is `14.42564679`

This will preserve the `double` and will not need a conversion to `string`