# c# - Show a decimal to 6 decimal places

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Double.ToString with N Number of Decimal Places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059759/double-tostring-with-n-number-of-decimal-places)

I want to show a decimal to 6 decimal places, even if it contains 6 x 0's
For example:

```
3.000000
5.100000
3.456789
```

and so forth, is this possible?

Comment: Check http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/ - I'm sure this has been asked many times before though

Comment: One: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359916/format-to-two-decimal-places. Two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884749/format-a-double-to-8-decimal-places. Three: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168592/force-a-string-to-2-decimal-places.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use `N6` as the [numeric format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
myDecimal.ToString("N6");
```

or

```
string.Format("{0:N6}", myDecimal);
```

Comment: The problem with that is, that is converts it to a string, i need to keep it in a decimal format, as that is the datatype stored in the database.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff What you want looks strange because decimal format has nothing to do with its formatted output.

Answer (score 7):

```
Decimal d = 20;
d.ToString("0.000000");
```