# Display 6 digits only using display format attribute C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Example
Value 2.546400000
I want 2.546400

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}")]
public decimal? TrackingErrorHigh { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking here. Where are you displaying the data? Is this an ASP.NET MVC view?

Comment: Here, I want to Display 6 digits for decimal number

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# - Show a decimal to 6 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412882/c-sharp-show-a-decimal-to-6-decimal-places)

Comment: I think there is a already around ~5 questions from displaying decimal for each possible number of digits.

Answer (score 1):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:N6}")]
public decimal? TrackingErrorHigh { get; set; }
```

or custom formatting

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:############.000000}")]
public decimal? TrackingErrorHigh { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_UI_WebControls_BoundField_DataFormatString) - taken from there:

To Displays numeric values in number format (including group separators and optional negative sign). You can specify the number of decimal places. You use {0:N}

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:N6}")]
public decimal? TrackingErrorHigh { get; set; }
```